# OpenLayers 3 BBOX strategy

Tags: openlayers-3

Given this example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/vector-wfs.js and using BBOX strategy , does it mean it is necessary to use  `&bbox=' + extent.join(',')` part in source URL?

> The OpenLayers3 Strategy BBOX strategy says “request new features
>   whenever the map bounds are outside the bounds of the previously
>   requested set of features.”

Comment: I have answered what I think is your question -- it comes from a mistake in the example comments, as BBOX does not refer to the BBOX of the map extent, but the tile extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the `&bbox=' + extent.join(',')` if required. If you take it out, you will get no wfs features at all. The example is actually somewhat misleading, in that, it calls it a BBOX strategy, whereas in fact it is a `createTile` strategy, using the BBOX from each underlying tile, as the wfs BBOX. If you look internally at the source code for [ol.source.ServerVector](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/source/servervectorsource.js) you will find a function `loadFeatures` that calls `ol.loadingstrategy.createTile` from [ol.loadingstrategy](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/loadingstrategy.js) which returns the required extents for each tile, which is then used for each wfs call. That is the extent that you see in the extent.join above.

Or to look at it another way, for every call to get an imagery tile, there is a corresponding call to a wfs tile -- which you can verify by looking in the network tab of your browser's dev tools. So, really, this is a tile BBOX strategy, not a view BBOX strategy.

I thoroughly recommend getting local debugging working for OL3 to understand what is going on. You can do that either by loading [ol-debug.js](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol-debug.js), for a non-compressed version of the js, or by setting up a local server, see [these instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123449/how-do-i-create-a-local-web-gis-server-using-node-js)

Comment: Now I am confused more than before, because I removed `&bbox=' + extent.join(',')` part from my url (because it does not work with GeoServer CQL filter) and my strategy is bbox and I have all features.

Comment: Really, it didn't work for me, debugging locally, against the wfs provided in the OL example. Could it be that you are simply getting all features from Geoserver? If Geoserver doesn't have a bbox, it will return a number of features for a layer, if that layer is small enough, you might appear to get everything. If you try removing bbox from the OL example, you will see nothing.

Comment: I am not getting anything back from your wfs. I see requests like this, but it is just hanging: http://loom-gis.geo.ut.ee:8080/geoserver/ermas/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ermas:testdata_geopnt&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&maxFeatures=20&srsname=EPSG:3301&callback=jQuery111007609058504458517_1417769630837&_=1417769630838

Comment: I really can't comment on it. For me request is working. Strange.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6nas4xq2/4/ I have updated you fiddle (sorry, my vpn was blocking your wfs, for some reason). If you take out maxFeatures, look what happens. You get nothing. set it to maxFeatures=200, look what happens. As I said above, as you have no BBOX, your server is simply responding to maxFeatures.

Comment: Just try to wait for a minute and with no maxFeatures it will respond with all the features (it just take some time, about half a minute )

Comment: OK, because if you have no maxFeatures and no BBOX then it defaults to whatever the Geoserver default is for maxFeatures (off the top of my head, 2000). However, the point remains, set maxFeatures = 2 you will see 2 features. Remove maxFeatures and set a BBOX=.... and you will get the features in the bounding box. Leave both maxFeatures adn BBOX out, you will get the default maxFeatures (after a long delay), which will be arbitrary and not based on any extents. I found this out testing a wfs with 450 million features in. I was looking at London, and got 20,000 features in Scotland.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. I wonder does adding `&CQL_FILTER=(bbox(geometry,'  + extent.join(',') + ')` will do the same thing as `&bbox=' + extent.join(',')`

Comment: Have a look at your wfs.xml in your geoserver_data directory. In ours, we have <maxFeatures>100000</maxFeatures>. This is what you are seeing. Try setting this to 0, restart your server, remove maxFeatures from your request, you will see nothing.

Comment: Yes, I would think that CQL_FILTER= ought to have the same effect as setting bbox=... However, that is another question :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I spent quite a lot of time on this, debugging locally, looking at source code, etc, so, if it has answered your question, it would be nice if you would accept the answer :-)

Comment: Using the bbox CQL filter does the same thing but is much slower. If you compare the NET/XHR timelines in Firebugs you will see that the processing on the Geoserver side takes longer.